# One variable type that refers to all classes

Tags: c#, oop

Say I have two classes such as:

```
public class Pineapple
{
public bool Ripe{get;set;}
public string State{get;set;}
}
```

and:

```
public class Bean
{
public string Type{get;set;}
public bool Bloats{get;set;}
}
```

I want to return an observable collection of those two classes in one method. This is what I mean rather than have:

```
public ObservableCollection<Pineapple> GetPineapples()
{
//some code that fetches pine apples
}
```

and yet another method:

```
public ObservableCollection<Bean> GetBeans()
{
//some code that fetches beans
}
```

what do I put @T ie ObservableCollection that refers to both of those classes

Comment: How about using `inheritance` here ? You could create a base class from which these classes get their properties and you can have a common base class to refer to

Comment: I want to implement an Interface since I have many of those classes with very similar method signatures e.g. FetchItems() could return a collection either of Pineapples or Beans

Comment: See @Andy's Answer. That is what I was pointing to. Something similar to that pattern would be helpful for your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have base class, for example `Plant`, that both of `Pineapple` and `Bean` should be inherited from (or interface, for example `IPlant`, both should implement).

Then you can do something like:

```
public class Plant {}

public class Pineapple : Plant ...

public class Bean: Plant ...

public ObservableCollection<Plant> GetPlants()
```

Comment: Works for classes with similar properties but what of classes whose properties are not similar and yet the methods are similar.

Comment: @MbithyMbithy you can put into base class (or into interface depending on what exactly you've decided to do) only properties/methods common to all classes you're planning to implement. If there are no such common properties/methods - your base class can be empty and in this case it will be used only as "root" of your class hierarchy, and common type you can use in in return result of your collection.

Comment: Making use of interface combined with inheritance helps but I wish one would just do **ObservableCollection<class>** :P

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something called ViewModel (it's generally used for web though and is just a proxy-class that provides some information about different classes) and you can add c'tors for every class you have;

```
public class Info
{
    public string Info1 { get; set; }
    public bool Info2 { get; set; }

    public Info(Pineapple p)
    {
        this.Info1 = p.State;
        this.Info2 = p.Ripe;
    }

    public Info(Bean b)
    {
        this.Info1 = b.Type;
        this.Info2 = b.Bloats;
    }
}
```

P.S.

But if you have many classes you should really consider using abstract class / interface.